# Making Table with nested SetDelay functions is very slow

Tags: functions, list-manipulation

I am trying to write a function which returns a list of lists of eigenenergies available for a quantum well. The code is here:

```
ml=1;
V0=0.3;
hbar=1
eVtoJ=1;
z0[L_,V0_]:=(L/2)*Sqrt[2*ml*V0*eVtoJ]/hbar //FullSimplify
tempRootsEven[L_,V0_]:={ToRules[Reduce[Tan[z]==Sqrt[(z0[L,V0]/z)^2-1] && 0<z<z0[L,V0],z,Reals]]};
tempRootsOdd[L_,V0_]:={ToRules[Reduce[-Cot[z]==Sqrt[(z0[L,V0]/z)^2-1] && 0<z<z0[L,V0],z,Reals]]};
evenRoots[L_,V0_]:=If[FreeQ[tempRootsEven[L,V0],z],{},z/.tempRootsEven[L,V0]];
oddRoots[L_,V0_]:=If[FreeQ[tempRootsOdd[L,V0],z],{},z/.tempRootsOdd[L,V0]];
OddEigenEnergies[L_,V0_]:=(2*root^2*hbar^2*1*^3)/(ml*L^2*eVtoJ)/.root->oddRoots[L,V0];
EvenEigenEnergies[L_,V0_]:=(2*root^2*hbar^2*1*^3)/(ml*L^2*eVtoJ)/.root->evenRoots[L,V0];
EigenEnergies[L_,V0_]:=Sort[Join[EvenEigenEnergies[L,V0],OddEigenEnergies[L,V0]]];
```

This works fine for a single L and V0, however the solution is incredibly slow when I try to run it in a Table command where I am varying L. The expected output looks like this:

```
EnergyTable=Table[{L,EigenEnergies[L,V0]},{L,5*^-10,15*^-9,0.5*^-9}]
Out: { {5.x10^-10,{209.722} , {1x10^-9,{75,121} , ..., {15x10^-9,{root1,root2,root3,etc} }
```

I don't have mathematica outside of my VSN so these are just random numbers and aren't actual solutions but that would be the format.

The issue is that this takes a very long time to run for the 30 or so widths I am trying to make in the Table. If I remove the setDelays then all the entries in the table end up with the same values.

Essentially the question I am asking is how to make a function which uses Table with an input dependent on that tables iterator.

Comment: I am 100% sure you may get help by posting a MWE with all needed code.

Comment: I edited the post to include a MWE. Not sure the exact code will compile because I can't copy paste into my mathematica notebook to check for a type but I tried to copy it as best as possible.